# Android 6.0 FTP server with external SD card write support?

Tags: wi-fi, 6.0-marshmallow, external-sd, ftp

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 phone with Android 6.0.1.

After upgrading to 6.0.1 (from 5.0), none of the FTP servers I've tried can write to external SD card. The only one that sort of works is FTPDroid, but it requires root to do that and doesn't work anymore since I reset my phone (and it's an outdated piece of software).

Does anyone know of a server that can do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For my case SwiFTP is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

com.theolivetree.ftpserver is the only one that work. But you need to set home dir to the external SDCard.

Answer (score -4):

Go to settings and select your external SD card as home directory of FTP server.

Comment: Why would changing the home directory make writes there more likely to succeed?